# How do I initialize an array of arrays in BCPL?

Tags: arrays, initialization, bcpl

I tried `let stringArr = newvec(12);` and then attempted to initialize each spot in the array as such: `let stringArr!i = newvec(5);` but that returns an error telling me I cannot do that. Is there anyone here who can help me with this dinosaur language?

Comment: Wow, where is BCPL still in use?

Comment: @Barmar Twitter.               Just kidding, a specific college course.

Comment: I don't see the `!` character anywhere in the BCPL reference manual http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/bcpl.pdf

Comment: Ahh, it looks like that's in the 1979 version of BCPL, not the 1967 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're stretching my memory a bit (to the extent of about three decades) but I seem to recall that `let` was used only for creating *new* local variables (also functions and possibly other things, but that's not really relevant for your question).

So the statement `let stringArr = newvec(12)` is valid in creating the new variable `stringArr` or, more precisely, a 12-cell anonymous vector and the `stringArr` variable holding the *address* of that vector.

However, `let stringArr!i = newvec(5)` is *not* valid, because `stringArr!i` isn't actually a new variable. It's simply the memory contents of cell number `i` in the already-existing `stringArr` vector.

In other words, the statement `let stringArr = newvec(12)` creates both the initial pointer cell *and* the second layer of pointers, which won't point anywhere useful yet:

```
+-----------+
| stringArr | ---+
+-----------+    |    +-------------+
                 +--> | stringArr!0 | --> ?
                      +-------------+
                      | stringArr!1 | --> ?
                      +-------------+
                      :      :      :
                      +-------------+
                      | stringArr!N | --> ?
                      +-------------+
```

And, since the pointers already exist, you shouldn't be using `let` to set them.

It's similar in C in that you wouldn't write:

```
int xyzzy[10];        // Make array of ten elements.
int xyzzy[0] = 42;    // Set first element to something.
```

since the second line isn't supposed to be defining a *new* variable, rather it's intent is simply to set one of the *existing* elements to a given value, done with `xyzzy[0] = 42`.

---

Hence the *right* way to do what you're trying to achieve in BCPL is to avoid using the `let` keyword for that second class of statements:

```
let stringArr = newvec(12)   // Create new vector AND new variable,
                             //   put vector address into cell for
                             //   that variable.
stringArr!i := newvec(5)     // Create new vector, put vector
                             //   address into EXISTING cell.
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is sound but both of my versions of BCPL (Martin Richard's and Robert Nordier's obcpl) complain about newvec() and also require := rather than = in the second line. I got it working with:

```
let stringArr = getvec(12)
stringArr!i := getvec(12)
```

John Boutland

Comment: Thanks for that edit, wogsland. I didn't know (and still don't) how to get the code in that format. John

Comment: John, I suspect you've probably figured it out in the 3.5 years since you posted this answer :-) But, just in case, you have to ensure there's a blank line before your code and that each line of code starts with four spaces. You can mark a text block and then use CTRL-K to code-indent it. Alternatively, there's a triple-backtick method as well but I never use that so can't advise.